# Webpart Blocking Create View on other list

Tags: content-query-web-part

I created a webpart from an announcement list (Add Announcement List > Open in Designer > Copy to file > Import webpart to page) and display this webpart above main datasheet data list. Users want to create custom views from the data list (Below the webpart) but cannot do so now as when I am on the page I have to select the webpart tickbox (as if deleting announcement from it) so that the list ribbon (with list settings/customise form etc.) shows up and this only gives me the option to modify the webpart, not the data list, where a user would want to create a new data view for example.

How can I set the data list to be able to show list ribbon related to it and be able to create new data list views from it? It seems like because the webpart is at the top of the page (but below ribbon) it only give me options to manipulate that. The webpart is listed as a list but it is derived from a list, however I do not want it to be a list now if I can help it. Hope that makes some sense....

I am a beginner in sharepoint and have limited to no experience in coding or advanced work so am hoping that I can achieve a fix without too much coding work.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

A List View WebPart only shows the data in a list.

It is **not** a list itself. It's just another way to view the data.

To create a new view of the list to display in the WebPart you need to navigate to the list behind the WebPart and create it there. That's where the ribbon options will be present.

If that doesn't make sense let me know and I can elaborate.

Comment: Doesn't make sense in the context of how I can redo this so that I have webpart above my datalist and be able to still access the list settings ribbon of my data view list.

Comment: For all intents and purposes the webpart seems to be a list as I can bring up the list settings ribbon and manipulate it.

Comment: First, it isn't a list. It's a view of a list. Second, maybe I'm confused about your question. If you check the tickbox the list's ribbon appears. If you have adequate permission you can create the view there. Do you want this or not want this?

Comment: If it is a view of a list would it not show the ribbon anymore? I would think it wouldn't if it was just a view of a list but not sure. The announcement list does have a tick box next to each entry and if I click on that I can display the list ribbon.

If I click on my data view list below this I cannot bring up the ribbon so cannot create custom views for it, this is what the users want but also they want the announcement list.

Comment: The announcement list is set up to accept emails from my SSIS package to give users announcement about data in the data list being updated.

I am, owner of site so cannot see how permissions would be an issue here with creating custom views with the data list, and I can create a custom view on the announcement list.

The problem seems to be that the webpart is at a top level of the page and the page only accepts one list that can be customised, and in this case it sees the webpart as a list, even though as you say it is not really a list but a view of a list.